# How to replace textarea component with some text

Tags: jquery

I am using below code to replace the textarea component with some another text (lets suppose 'abc1').

But it is NOT working. Anyone please help !

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(".textbrand").replaceWith("abc1"); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="textbrand">
      <textarea name="S1" rows="3" cols="30"></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in the Javascript console?

Comment: `$(".textbrand").html("abc1");` try with this.

Comment: Checkout the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Works very well in the snippet below. **Check if you have jQuery included in your HTML.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(".textbrand").replaceWith("abc1"); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="textbrand">
      <textarea name="S1" rows="3" cols="30"></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about .html()?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(".textbrand").html("abc1"); 
});
```